# How to put multilevel values into database?

Tags: php, rest, mysqli

How I can put all Phone values into

Phone field in Contact table in MySQL database using PHP Form ?

What will be the insert query to post it on database ?[image]

So that If I generate JSON file from that database, It will looks like following JSON format.

```html
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should have a separate table for the phone numbers with something like: `id, phone_number, type, contact_id` where `type` is either `mobile`, `home` or `office`. That way you can easily add more phone number types if needed or have more than one of each type.

Comment: Can you give me an example or web link?

Comment: I don't have any specific link or tutorial but search for "mysql junction table" and "mysql join".